# What to use as a "button" in a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I've been looking through various websites and came across multiple ways to make "buttons". What are the pros and cons to each way?

```
<div class='btn'><a>Click Me!</a></div>

<span class='btn'><a>Click Me!</a></span>

<a class='btn'>Click Me!</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn{
 display:inline-block;
 min-width:100px;
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: display-inline:block; should be display: inline-block;

Comment: What is the functionality of said "button"? Page navigation? Form submission? The semantics are intrinsically tied to the functionality, so it's impossible to answer without knowing that.

Comment: Page navigation. Although I'd like to know how it is tied to the functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are all three the exact same thing.  They're all just a link, the only difference is that parent class is used as a selector target.  They are effectively identical.

There is one differences between the first and second 2, though.  a div, by default, is a block element while a span and an a tag are both inline, thus a dive fills up the entire width of the container, but that can be changed with css (as your example does).

Why not just, I don't know.. call me crazy.. but why not just use an actual button?

The only reason I can think of to NOT use a button is if you want the links to be search spider visible.  If you're going to use javascript to post a form, then i suggest using a button instead.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with an anchor tag, just easier to type, and change later on if necessary. All I have to do is add the btn class to any existing link as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [this article](http://css-tricks.com/when-and-when-not-to-use-an-anchor-tag/) by Chris Coyer.  It's titled "[When (and when not to) use an anchor tag?](http://css-tricks.com/when-and-when-not-to-use-an-anchor-tag/)".

Here's an excerpt:

> I think if you are going to put a href attribute on the anchor that
>   actually does something even if JavaScript is disabled, then the
>   anchor is the right choice. If the app is totally JavaScript dependent
>   all behavior is attached via JavaScript, I guess it doesn't really
>   matter what element you use. Maybe it's even better not to use an
>   anchor since the behavior probably bears no resemblance to what anchor
>   links do. You could probably talk me out of that though. The thing is,
>   anchors give you ("for free") lots of the visual functionality that
>   you want with deep browser support. So...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `a` tag (more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_a.asp)), but the `span` tag is inline and the `div` tag isn't. Otherwise they're all pretty much the same.

Comment: True, but as I pointed out.. his css changes the display mode to inline-block for all elements, so that is really a moot point.

Comment: mmm, didn't really notice that. I guess it's just a matter of taste, then? :P

Answer (score 0):

the `<div>` and the `<span>` must have an action using javascript but the `<a>` can have a link to another page without using java script code

Comment: All three examples use an a tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form submit i prefer to use a `input` button. As it doesn't need further Javascript code to submit a form.

The difference between `span` and `div` is that div is a container element whereas span is not. How this is helpful to you? Check out his [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/aa011000a.htm).

If you dont want to apply any style and if you are okay in writing (or) if its a simple get request to server (or) if you are willing to write some javascript event handlers then go with `anchor` tags

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is the third one because you use only one DOM element instead of two. This will improve the performance and will make your code more semantically because you are not creating empty DOM elements for styling.

In addition, with the example 1 and 2 if the anchor is smaller than 100px the clickable zone will be smaller than the example 3.